# Using hash tables instead of lists for buckets in hash tables

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, hash-tables

Say instead of using a linked list as buckets for a hash table of size $m$, we use another hash table of size $p$ as buckets this time. What would be the average case for this problem?

I looked up perfect hashing and I got a very close algorithm, and it is $O(1)$. Can someone please clarify?

Comment: "What would be the average case for this problem?" -- what exactly do you mean; lookup time?

Comment: Related: ["Why can't we use a hash tables for collision resolving in hash tables?"](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6348/why-cant-we-use-a-hash-tables-for-collision-resolving-in-hash-tables)

Answer (score 6):

Using a hash table with $n$ buckets and a hash function $h_n : S \rightarrow \{0, 1, ..., n - 1\}$ , where each bucket is a hash table with $m$ buckets and a hash function $h_m : S \rightarrow \{0, 1, ..., m - 1\}$, is equivalent to a hash table wit $nm$ buckets and a hash function $h_{nm} : S \rightarrow \{0, 1, 2, ..., nm - 1\}$ where $h_{nm}(x) = mh_n(x) + h_m(x)$. In other words, using more than one level has no effect whatsoever on the complexity: it's the same as a for a garden-variety hash table.

Perfect hashing is a completely separate issue.

Comment: One would presume, though not mentioned in the question, that each bucket would have an independent size $m_n$. The sum of these would also be bound by the total number of items in the hashmap.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Possibly, but that's just playing around with some of the expressions, not the answer.

Comment: @Patrick87: Sure, but there is no reason that every secondary hash table has to have the same size.  Suppose $n_i$ is the number of elements in the $i$th bucket of the primary hash table.  If we use a random hash function $h_i \colon S \to \{0, 1, \dots, n_i^2\}$, we get constant-time lookups in linear space _with high probability_, not just in expectation.  This scheme is sometimes called "perfect hashing".